# Не могу получить объект JList из выбранной JPanel через событие

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Начал работать в NetBeans,и уже встретился с проблемой ,которую без вашей помощи я не решу(гуглил 2 дня)!
Вообщем мне надо получить объект `JList` из выбранной панели `JPanel`,но не получаться найти класс `JList` из компонентов `JPanel`.

пробовал получить `JList` так

```
jTabbedPane1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

           Container   ob =(JPanel) jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent();
            System.out.println("Tab COMP : "+ ob.getClass().getName());
            int count = ob.getComponentCount();
            System.out.println("count = "+count);



            Ent(jList1);
            Component comp1 = (JScrollPane) ob.getComponent(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Component comp = ob.getComponent(i);
                System.out.println("comp name: "+comp.getClass()+"   "+i);
            }
            JScrollPane pan = (JScrollPane) ob.getComponent(1);
            int count2=pan.getComponentCount();



            for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++) {
                Component co = pan.getComponent(i);
                System.out.println("Scroll comp : "+co.getClass());
            }
```

Вывод в консоли таков :

```
Tab COMP : javax.swing.JPanel

count = 3

comp name: class javax.swing.JLabel 0

comp name: class javax.swing.JScrollPane 1

comp name: class javax.swing.JButton 2

Scroll comp : class javax.swing.JViewport

Scroll comp : class javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar

Scroll comp : class javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar
```

Я бы, конечно, мог напрямую писать события для каждого `JList`'a ,но у меня их достаточно много,я бы хотел сократить код.

А вот что создал сам NetBeans

```
jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 135, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(7, 7, 7))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel1);

    jList4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane5.setViewportView(jList4);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Зачем вам нужно получать объекты? В чём состоит задача?

Comment: Задача заключается в том ,что бы создать jTabbedPane (панель вкладок), затем добавить туда 4 панели ,и на каждой панели есть кнопка,лейбел и список. А смысл заключается в том,что бы при переключении вкладок и выборе значений из листа,это значение переносилось в другой лист.Ну как бы попроще объяснить,как будто меню листаешь и кладешь в корзину,на каждой странице меню свои блюда

Comment: Я просто не хочу писать под каждый лист свое событие,я думаю можно сделать это как то попроще.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ответ.
Может кому будет интересно

```
scrollPane.getViewport().getView()
```